# Identify a query written with NEST in Elastic slowlog

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to tune my elasticsearch cluster taking a look at the all the queries done through the slowlog functionality (slowlog generated on file -> logstash -> another elastic cluster).

I would like to identify a query from a business side. It would be great if I could add something (like a comment) that the slowlog could parse in order to have something to put in a field with logstash.

So far I haven't found anything, any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the [audit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html) log functionality together with the `xpack.security.audit.logfile.events.emit_request_body` option. We're using it to identify the origin of the request, operations invoked and the issuing user because we have security enabled.

If you can't identify the NEST query only by origin IP, think about creating a NEST user and issue the queries using this user.